# Checking pop mail account using terminal

Tags: command-line, email, mail-user-agent

Is there any command in unix to check a pop3 account using terminal? I mean, type the server/username/password of a pop3 account and see if the username/password is correct?

Comment: `getmail` will also work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `telnet` to connect to the mail server and talk [POP3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) to check your credentials:

```
$ telnet pop.gmx.net 110
Trying 212.227.17.185...
Connected to pop.gmx.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK POP server ready H migmx028 0MAbjW-1YwF4D0ml8-00BiVl
USER spamaccount80@gmx.de
+OK password required for user "spamaccount80@gmx.de"
PASS typeyourpassword
-ERR Error retrieving your GMX emails. Your connection is not encrypted. Enable SSL in your mail program. Instructions: https://ssl.gmx.net
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Well, this failed because most mail server require a [SSL/TLS encrypted session](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2595) nowadays. So instead of using `telnet` you can use `socat`:

```
$ socat - OPENSSL:pop.gmx.net:995
+OK POP server ready H migmx113 0MC062-1Yzese0KO7-00AVNE
USER spamaccount80@gmx.de
+OK password required for user "spamaccount80@gmx.de"
PASS typeyourpassword
+OK mailbox "spamaccount80@gmx.de" has 13518 messages (191718918 octets) H migmx113
```

If you type a wrong password, the server will probably say something like:

```
-ERR authentication failed
```

Or instead of `socat` you probably have `openssl` laying around:

```
$ openssl s_client -quiet -connect pop.gmx.net:995
depth=2 C = DE, O = Deutsche Telekom AG, OU = T-TeleSec Trust Center, CN = Deutsche Telekom Root CA 2
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
+OK POP server ready H migmx108 0MWpjO-1YiwnK3ZfP-00XoK
```

Comment: Might be worth including the command line for plain ol' POP3 without SSL

Comment: @roaima Good remark. I've added `telnet` and `openssl` examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check your pop3 mail accounts then take a look at the following terminal mail clients:

1. pine
2. alpine
3. mutt

There are many more, but those are the most popular ones that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest mutt.
Why?Because support tls and even kerberos for single sign on
If use single sign on put on .muttrc

```
set imap_authenticators="gssapi"
```